Exact manipulation of relationship involving sum produces non-exact values
I have the following peculiar situation and I am trying to understand it.
I have two unknown vectors (parameters) called $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$, which I am trying to write as functions of each other, starting with the following given relation between their components
$$ B_{1l}=\sum_{n} B_{2n} \frac{a v_{1n}J_{1}(v_{1n}a/r_{0})}{(2 a^{2}k^{2}+v_{1l}^{2})J_{0}(v_{1l})}, \ \ \ \  (1)$$
where $v_{1n}$ denote the $n$th zero of the $J_{1}$ Bessel function of the first kind, and all other symbols denote real physical parameters (constants). Note that $l$ and $n$ are just integer indices for the vectors $B_1$ and $B_2$.
If I now multiply both sides by $J_{1}(v_{1p}a/r_{0})$ and integrate in $a$ from $0$ to $r_{0}$, making use of the Bessel integral identity $\int^{1}_{0}xJ_{1}(\alpha x)J_{1}(\beta x)=\delta_{\alpha\beta}J_{2}^{2}(\alpha)/2$ where $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$ is Kronecker's delta function, I obtain a relationship that links $B_{1l}$ and $B_{2p}$ as
$$ B_{2p}= B_{1l}\left[\frac{2 J_{0}(v_{1l})}{v^{2}_{1p}J_{2}(v_{1p})}\left(2k^{2} r^{2}_{0} + v^{2}_{1l} +\frac{v^{2}_{1l}}{J_{2}(v_{1p})}\right)\right]=B_{1l} \ \psi_{lp}, \ \ \ \ (2)$$
where $\psi_{lp}$ has simply collected all the constant terms in the square brackets, for any given value of the indices ($l,p$).
So, to check that this relationship works, I can assume a given series of $B_{1l}$ values, then use equation (2) above to generate the corresponding $B_{2p}$ values. To verify that the method works, I plug these $B_{2p}$ values back in equation (1) and see if the values I obtain for $B_{1l}$ are correct.
I did this with the help of Wolfram Mathematica. But, even though my calculation above was exact, I was surprised that the result had small error, which seemed to depend on the number of terms in sum.
For example, choosing only 10 values for the index $l$ and $p$ and generating the random values for $B_{1l}$ as:
$0.89439, 0.392527, 0.0323896, 0.512612, 0.195394, 0.544358, 0.899124,
0.286951, 0.695147, 0.694467, 0.453776, 0.0498617, 0.294436, 0.0694178, 0.868041, 0.889135, 0.00066131, 0.0340648, 0.224834, 0.889412$,
then following the method above, I get
$0.871777, 0.382603, 0.0315707, 0.499651, 0.190453, 0.530594,0.876389, 0.279695, 0.677568, 0.676905, 0.4423, 0.0486007, 0.286989, 0.067662, 0.846084, 0.866643, 0.00064458, 0.0332029, 0.219145, 0.866906$.
Plotting each value (of $B_{1l}$) and the corresponding value returned by the method above gives:

And plotting the relative error for each of value shows:

If I increase the number of points to 200, here is the new error plot:

In these plots, the x-axis is just the running index ($l=1, 2, 3, ...$) of the index.
It is clear to me that the error is decreasing when the series has more terms, but I don't understand why, given that we did not have any postulate to start with that this series is finite or infinite, and since our derivation is exact (no approximations). I also don't understand why the error seems to grow for the values that have higher index (error curve going up). Any suggestions on why these things are being observed -- or how to make it exact -- would be appreciated.

How many terms are you using in $\sum_n$, your equation (1)? I'm guessing it converges pretty slowly.

@aruralreader The definition itself does not have a set upper limit for the sum. In my two examples I first used 20 terms, then 200 terms (see figures). But what I don’t understand is why should we consider convergence here in the first place? Say that equation (1) is defined with upper limit N=20 for the sum. Our derivation proceeded  without any approximation so it should be exact. So wouldn’t we get an exact agreement with just 20 terms? Am I missing something?
